# Circumference of an ImplicitRegion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, geometry

I define an ellipse by using an ImplicitRegion:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[4 z^2 + r^2 == 10, {z, r}]
```

I would like to get the perimeter of this ellipse. I was hoping to simply use Perimeter:

```
Perimeter[R]
```

However this returns "Undefined." Are there any suggestions on how to compute the perimeter of an ImplicitRegion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `ArcLength` work for one-dimension region which imbeded in two-dimension region.

```
R = ImplicitRegion[4 z^2 + r^2 == 10, {z, r}]
RegionMeasure[R]
ArcLength[R]
```

> `2 Sqrt[10] EllipticE[-3]`

- `Perimeter` work for a two dimension region.

```
R2 = ImplicitRegion[4 z^2 + r^2 <= 10, {z, r}]
Perimeter[R2]
```

> `2 Sqrt[10] EllipticE[-3]`